# JQuery array values to php array key pair

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have JQuery array like `[1_1,1_2,1_3,2_2,2_1,5_2]` before underscore is key and after is value. I want data like key 1 and all its values.. then key 2 and all its values.

Basically the array is coming from parent child checkboxes. before underscore its the parent id and after child selected ids.

Parent check box is automatically selected if we select child. and child checkboxes value is like... parentID_Child id..

i have getting array with this code.

```
var pageArray = [];
var actionArray = [];
$('input[name="action"]:checked').each(function() {
    actionArray.push($(this).val());
});
alert(actionArray);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what code you have done so far

Comment: This is pretty easy but you have to try it by own.

Comment: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you _haven't_ tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: code updated. please check

Comment: @Saclt7 please check now

Comment: Would it not be a better idea to create this array in the shape that you want it to be, rather then now try and fiddle with it?

Comment: How do you create this array, please show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly that was the best option i can create array like that. so parent id with childs but now i have to split them.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated my question. please check

Comment: Why the PHP tag, I dont see any PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly because i can send same array to php as well. so if any solution in PHP or JQuery both will work.

Comment: answer: loop, split, push

Comment: @NappingRabbit can you show with code ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly any thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an object which will be read as associative array in php

```
var actionObj = {};
$('input[name="action"]:checked').each(function() {
    var parts = this.value.split('_'),
        key = parts[0],
        value= parts[1];

    actionObj[key] = actionObj[key] || [];
    actionObj[key].push(value)
});
```

Comment: Thanks man i will give it a try.